# Is there any way to override a mailto field with another field?

Tags: html, mailto

AKA, if I have two fields (one radio button group and one textarea that only appears if the "other" radio button is pressed) how would I make it so the input from the text area overrides the "other" button having it's value placed in the mailto?

E.g., I want this to happen:

```
field1=text from text area
```

NOT this:

```
field1=other
field2=text from text area
```

Could I set the value of the "other" radio button in field1 to the text coming from the text area?

Alternatively, could I do anything to prevent a certain field from appearing in the mailto fields?

Comment: This is more of an "I have no idea where to even start" kind of thing. I was just thrust into learning HTML.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is not for giving ideas where to start!..

Comment: You should really present So with a problem, not a general code request or off topic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future, please ensure you present SO with a code issue, not a general question or request. However, you would use a JQuery change handler, like so:

```
$('#mastertextboxid').on('input', function(){ //executes every time master's text is updated
  $('#slavetextboxid').value($('#mastertextboxid').text()); //updates the values
})
```

This will overwrite any text in the slave textbox when the master textbox is changed, but the User will still be able to input into the slave textbox. It's known as **One way data binding**.

[image]